# Redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to a file, except for standard output/error of system()

Tags: perl, io-redirection

I am trying to run a Perl script in Linux and log all output to STDOUT and STDERR to a file using:

```
open (STDOUT, "| tee -i $transcript_file");
open (STDERR, "| tee -ai $transcript_file");
```

The script that uses this works roughly as follows:

1. Create an environment for running a tool. Has many `print`, `warn` and possibly `die` statements.
2. Run the tool (Currently using `system` command). This produces a lot of output which I want to appear on STDOUT, but not in the logfile (The tool creates its own logfile).
3. Analyze the results, cleanup and exit. Has many `print`, `warn` and possibly `die` statements.

Everything works correctly except I would like to exclude the output of step 2 from the log. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks,

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow. Please help me in asking questions correctly if I have not done so.

Comment: Very OK question. In general: don't use tag names ("perl") in your title. I changed the title to state the programming problem, instead of the effect you want to achieve with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with  Sobrique's advice to use a special function `print_and_log`. But if you *really* want to do it the way you set out to do, you can `dup`  `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, redirect them to your log and then use `open3` to run your tool with the dup'ed original standard output and error file descriptors

```
use  IPC::Open3;

# dup the old standard output and error 
open(OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!\n";
open(OLDERR, ">&STDERR") or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!\n";

# reopen stdout and stderr
open (STDOUT, "|tee $transcript_file") or die "Can't reopen STDOUT: $!\n";
open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT")              or die "Can't reopen STDERR: $!\n";

# print statements now write to log
print "Logging important info: blah!\n";
print STDERR "OOPS!\n";

# run your command; output will go to original stdout
# this will die() instead of returning say -1, so use eval() to catch errors
my $pid = open3(">&OLDOUT", "<&STDIN", ">&OLDERR", $command); 

# wash those dishes....
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
```

Comment: Hmm, nice line of thinking. Hadn't considered that approach. Certainly would lend itself to some more complicated tasks well.

Comment: Thanks, this worked wonderfully. It took some time to capture return value of the shell script (exit EXITCODE), but using $? >> 255 helped along with using eval like you suggested..

Answer (score 0):

Given you're reassigning `STDIN` and `STDOUT` then the short answer is no. You're capturing *everything* on `STDOUT` which includes your intermediate output.

You could probably close/reopen `STDOUT` for the bit where you didn't want it logging. 
But I'd suggest instead that you might want to consider what you're trying to accomplish - would a 'print_and_log' subroutine do what you're after?

Comment: `system` calls always write to file descriptors 1 and 2. These usually correspond to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` in Perl, but it is possible to manipulate them to map to other file descriptors.

Comment: not exactly. manipulation with STDOUT & STDERR give any effect only on most internat printings inside Perl. Unfortunately it doesn't affect externally called commands. Only physically reopenning works everywhere, system streams 1 & 2 must be reopenned and assigned into selected stream, file, terminal or .... /dev/null  .