# Warning within IPC::Open3 when using open3 twice

Tags: perl, ipcopen3

I am using [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open3) for the suggestion given by Hans Lub [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28365805/622310).

My issue is that the `open3` call works correctly for the first time, but subsequent invocations return the warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ne (!=) at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/IPC/Open3.pm line 215.
```

The code sample I am using looks like this:

```
use  IPC::Open3;

my $pid;
# dup the old standard output and error 
open(OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!\n";
open(OLDERR, ">&STDERR") or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!\n";

my $transcript_file = "transcript.temp";
# reopen stdout and stderr
open (STDOUT, "|tee -i $transcript_file") or die "Can't reopen STDOUT: $!\n";
open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT")              or die "Can't reopen STDERR: $!\n";

# print statements now write to log
print "Logging important info: blah!\n";
print STDERR "OOPS!\n";

#eval { $pid = open3("\*STDIN", "\*OLDOUT", "\*OLDERR", "ls"); }; # Tried this, but doesnt seem to help. Output does not appear on STDOUT.
eval { $pid = open3(">&STDIN", ">&OLDOUT", ">&OLDERR", "ls"); }; #This works correctly
waitpid( $pid, 0 );

eval { $pid = open3(">&STDIN", ">&OLDOUT", ">&OLDERR", "ls"); }; #First warning
waitpid( $pid, 0 );

eval { $pid = open3(">&STDIN", ">&OLDOUT", ">&OLDERR", "ls"); }; #Second warning
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
```

I apologize if I look to be trying to get others solve my problems, but I just can't seem to get around this, and looking inside Perl modules is beyond my current understanding.

Comment: I suggest you start by updating the `IPC::Open3` module. In the current version, line 215 is a blank line.

Comment: Try `open3(\*STDIN, \*OLDOUT, \*OLDERR)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the module is beyond my sphere of influence. I am forced to use what is available: Perl version 5.8.8, and Open3 V1.1.

Comment: @nwehhnhof, tried replacing all 3 eval open3's with your suggestion, but now the open3 output does not appear on transcript (intended) as well as STDOUT/STDERR (Unintended).

Comment: If this is a version issue, I guess I should delete this question altogether, since it addresses an "old problem" that's already fixed and does not help anybody else.

Comment: If updating to a new version isn't an option, looking for workarounds might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to give the same STDIN to multiple parallel process. `open3` thus assumes the handle you tell `open3` to use isn't used by anything else, so it closes it.

It looks like your children aren't using the STDIN you provide them, so you should provide a handle to `/dev/null`.

```
open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
$pid = open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way `open3` uses the file handles that you pass. If you use, say, `>&STDOUT` then the file handle is duped, the dupe is passed to the child process, and the parent's copy is *closed*. That means the second time you do the same thing you are duping a closed file handle, which doesn't have the effect you want.

The only way around this that I can see is to dupe the file handles separately and pass the dupes to the child process. It won't matter that the parent's copy of the dupes is closed because it still has the original `STDOUT` etc. Unfortunately it adds another three statements to each `open3` call, so you woul probably want to wrap the whole thing in a subroutine, like this.

```
my_open3('ls');
my_open3('ls');
my_open3('ls');

sub my_open3 {

  my @cmd = @_;
  my $pid;

  open IN_COPY,  '<&', STDIN  or die "Couldn't dup STDIN: $!";
  open OUT_COPY, '>&', STDOUT or die "Couldn't dup STDOUT: $!";
  open ERR_COPY, '>&', STDERR or die "Couldn't dup STDERR: $!";

  eval {
    $pid = open3('>&IN_COPY', '>&OUT_COPY', '>&ERR_COPY', @cmd);
  };

  waitpid $pid, 0;
}
```

This isn't the nicest of solutions, so if anyone can see anything better then please chime in. The only alternative I can see is to let the parent keep its own standard IO handles and use completely new ones to communicate with the child process each time. Then the parent would have mess with [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Select) to do the copying from the child output to its own `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

As `nwellnhof` says, if the child doesn't use its `STDIN` (as is the case with the `ls` command) then you can just pass `undef` as the first parameter. That saves duplicating one of three standard handles.

Comment: The first call to `open3` will consume all input on *stdin* anyway. So for subsequent invocations of `open3`, you can simply pass `undef` as first argument. (Or pass `undef` all the time if the called program doesn't read from *stdin*.)

Comment: @nwellnhof: Thanks. I've added a note on my solution.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This helped out.
Experimenting further showed that duping STDOUT and STDERR is not needed (Don't know why, as it should logically).
Since there was no need for STDIN which I was using earlier, passing undef makes the error go away.

Comment: @Abhishek: I've been unable to test this. Does it work as I've written it? If you describe your experience then it will be useful to others who come here looking for help with a similar problem

Comment: Umm.... This will actually not work as is. The problem is that at every call to the subroutine, IN_COPY, OUT_COPY and ERR_COPY are updated with the ones applicable at that moment (Redirected copies!). Therefore, anything printed inside open3 will appear both in the transcript file and the STDOUT/ERR.

Comment: A small change needed is to copy the standard inputs/outputs before the start of logging. Updating the answer to reflect this.

Comment: `OUT_COPY` and `ERR_COPY` are written to by the child process but read from the parent process. They should be input handles.

Comment: @mob: They're not read by the parent process. The parent has duped its own `STDOUT` and passed it to the child, so the child is sending output directly without intervention.

Comment: Well, the (logical) corrections I did to the code were rejected... The above code will not work correctly per my last comment. Hope future readers understand the changes from my comment.
-Abhishek

Comment: 1) Only STDIN is closed. You don'y need to copy STDOUT and STDERR. 2) Giving the same STDIN to multiple processes makes no sense, so you should probably open `/dev/null` instead of duping STDIN. 3) The first arg of `open3` should be `'<&...'` rather than `'>&...'`. 4) You call `waitpid` even when `open3` fails to launch a process.